# Netbeans code formatting issue

Tags: netbeans, netbeans6.8

For some reason the Format command (Source->Format) in Netbeans 6.8 is not representative of my configuration in Tools->Options->Editor. Is there something special I have to do to have my Editor options reflected in the Format command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, figured it out (just had to reopen the project I was working on).